# Access-Control-Allow_Headers CORS error when posting to .net WebApi from Javascript code via Axios

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, axios, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm executing a post request from javascript to a .net WebApi using Axios.  I added the following code to the Startup.cs of my WebApi to allow any header and accept traffic from localhost like so:

**Startup.cs ConfigureServices**

```
servies.AddCors(options => 
    {
      options.AddPolicy("AllowPolicy", 
        builder => builder
          .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8081")
          .AllowAnyHeader());
    });
```

The controller's action is decorated with the "EnableCors" attribute to apply the above policy

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("customers/{tenantNumber}")]
[EnableCors("AllowPolicy")
public async Task<ActionResult> AddCustomer(Customer customer){

}
```

I'm calling the above route via axios post method.  To do this I create an instance of axios and call the post method:

```
function addCustomer(customer){
    const custAPI = axios.create({
           baseURL: 'myURL',
           withCredentials: false,
           headers: {
           'Content-Type: 'application/json'
           'Authorization: null,
           'Accept': 'application/json'
           }
    });

    return custAPI().post("myWebApiURL", customer);
}
```

The following message is being returned:  **"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'webApi site' from origina 'local host client site' has been blocked by CORS policy:  Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response"**

I've tried removing the content-type header and changing the type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but can't seem to track down this error.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?  I've tried many of the solutions mentioned here but can seem to nail this one.

Comment: "preflight response" is the key. Browsers make a request using the OPTIONS method, so you'll need to add that to your server-side code.

Comment: Have you added `app.UseCors();` in Startup? Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-cors-with-attributes

Comment: @juunas....sorry didn't include that but yes, I added it to the Configure method.

Comment: `.AllowAnyMethod()`

Comment: @HereticMonkey... do you recommend creating an extension method, attribute, etc..?  Can you share a code snippet of what you're talking about?  I'm using .Net Core 3.1

Comment: I'd recommend not enabling CORS on a per-action basis, but rather on a per-application basis. Then all requests (including OPTIONS) going to your API are covered.

Comment: I don't think I want to open my entire app up to CORS...that would require additional coding to accommodate potential hacking.  I really only have one (or two) action methods that require CORS.  I looking for a simple solution as I have a pressing deadline to get this working

Comment: It could work well in my project.You need to check:1.it should be custAPI.post() not custAPI().post().2. be sure the client which will call web api url(.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8081")) is correct.Are you sure it is http not https?3.be sure the cors middleware order must be like below:app.UseRouting();app.UseCors();app.UseAuthorization();app.UseEndpoints(); 4.After resolving your issue,remember to add [FromBody] to your action.Refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834834/11398810

Comment: Please try to specify the headers in Startup.cs like:`WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType, "x-custom-header")`.Refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#preflight-requests. If still have problems,please use Fidller to catch the options and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the axios instance creation simple and instead provide things like `headers` as `config` parameter on the request, for example:

```
const custAPI = axios.create();

// Send request
const options = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
    }
};
const result = await custAPI.post(fullUrl, customer, options);
```

Note that your code as posted has several syntax errors with missing quotes and tries to use `custAPI` as a function rather than an object.